# Difference Between First Order Logic and Conjunctive Queries

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

What is the difference between First Order Logic and Conjunctive Queries ?

Can you for instance give an example of FO query and Conjunctive Query for the following statement?

Give the all the triples p,q,s in graph S that has edges among each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Erich Gradel & Phokion Kolaitis & Leonid Libkin, *Finite Model Theory and Its Applications* (2007), page 259 :

a *conjunctive query* is a formula like :

> $\varphi (x,y) \equiv \exists z ( E(x,z) \land E(z,y))$

Assuming that "a triples $p,q,s$ in a graph $S$ that has edges among each other" means that the three vertex form a "triangle", your query $q(p,q,s)$ can be defined by the following formula:

> $\varphi(p, q, r) \equiv (E(p,r) \land E(r,q) \land E(p,q))$.

Comment: Thanks Mauro. I was wondering what quantifier we need for this? Should we use a Universal Quantifier ?

Comment: @SharonPatel - I'm not sure ... I'm not very expert about *query language*, but I think that the aim of the formula is to "select" all objcets satisfying a certain condition. Let us try with a simpler example, and let $Even(x)$ the formula $\exists n(x = 2 \times n)$. This formula express a "predicate" true of all and only even numbers. If you quantify it with $\forall$, you will get : $\forall x Even(x)$ and this means : "all numbers are even" (that is a false statement). Now, what happens with the formula $\varphi(p,q,r)$ above ? if we quantify it with $\forall$ ... 1/2

Comment: @SharonPatel - ... we have the formula $\forall p \forall q \forall r ((E(p,r) \land E(r,q) \land E(p,q))$. This formula do not express any more a "condition" about the vertex of the graph; it express the fact that "all three vertex whatever are connected by edges". Is this the "intention" that we want to formalize with the above query ? 2/2

Comment: Mauro doesn't ∀p∀q∀r((E(p,r)∧E(r,q)∧E(p,q)) express give me all the vertexes connected by an edge that makes a triangle? As in - First Order Logic. I just learned that conjunctive queries don't have the universal quantifier hence this may not be expressible with ∀ for conjunctive queries but if we look at FO queries is this expressible that way then?

Comment: No, the quantified expression $\forall x P(x)$ does not express a "condition" that can be satisfied or not by the objects of your "domain of discourse"; it says that **all** the objects have the property $P(_)$. So, if you quantify your formula, what you express is the fact that three vertex whatever of the graph forms a triagle; and I think this will be true only if the graph has only three vertex.

Comment: @SharonPatel - I think that a query must be an *open* formula i.e.with one or more free variables : with one free var you will select a set; with two vars, you will select a binary relation; with three vars a ternary relation, and so on.